# Como fazer mais de um tipo de requisição ao servidor do Python?

Tags: python, socket, udp

Separei usando uma função, mas o código não recebe o 'data'.

CÓDIGO DO SERVIDOR COMPLETO:

```
import socket
import json
import sys

dicty = {
    'the': 'o, a, os, as',
    'hello': 'ola',
    'hi': 'oi',
    'good': 'bom',
    'ugly': 'feio',
    'bad': 'ruim, mal',
    'pretty': 'lindo(a)',
    'happy': 'feliz',
    'sad': 'triste',
    'yes': 'sim',
    'no': 'nao'
}



def buscar():
    data, adress = sock.recvfrom(4000)

    if data.decode('ascii') in dicty:
        sock.sendto(dicty[data.decode('ascii')].encode('ascii'), adress)
    else:
        sock.sendto(('0'.encode('ascii')), adress)

port = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
sock.bind((host, port))

dado, adress = sock.recvfrom(3000)
while True:
    if dado.decode('ascii') == 'Buscar':

        buscar()

    if dado.decode('ascii') != 'Buscar':

        sys.exit(0)
```

CÓDIGO DO CLIENTE COMPLETO:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import sys

port = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
sock.connect((host,port))

def buscar(): #função de buscar palavras
               sock.sendto(('Buscar'.encode('ascii')), (host,port))
               sock.sendto((e1.get().encode('ascii')), (host, port))
               data, adress = sock.recvfrom(4000)
               if data.decode('ascii')=='0':
                   lb2["text"] = 'Esse nome nao existe em nosso dicionario. Ajude-nos cadastrando uma nova palavra'
               else:
                   lb2["text"] = data.decode('ascii')

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry("900x500+100+100")
janela.title("DICIONARIO COLABORATIVO")

lb1 = Label(text="DICIONARIO INGLES-PORTUGUES") #titulo
lb1.place(x=4, y =30)

btn1 = Button(text="Buscar", command=buscar) #botao de busca
btn1.place(x=4, y=100)

lb2 = Label(text="") #local do significado
lb2.place(x=200, y=90)

lb3 = Label(text="Significado")
lb3.place(x=200,y=50)

e1 = Entry(janela) #recebe palavra
e1.place(x=4, y=50)

btn3 = Button(text='SAIR', command=janela.quit)
btn3.place(x=300,y=300)

janela.mainloop()
```

Não há erros. O servidor simplesmente fica esperando o cliente mandar algo eternamente.

Comment: Por que você tem "recvfrom(3000)" e *também* "recvfrom(4000)" no servidor ? Isso vai travar o programa...mas acho que o primeiro erro é que está faltando o "bind" da porta 3000 no cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz dessa forma, mas não dá certo:

```
dado, adress = sock.recvfrom(3000)
while True:
    if dado.decode('ascii') == 'Buscar':
        data, adress = sock.recvfrom(4000)

        if data.decode('ascii') in dicty:
            sock.sendto(dicty[data.decode('ascii')].encode('ascii'), adress)
        else:
            sock.sendto(('0'.encode('ascii')), adress)

        sock.bind((host, port))

    if dado.decode('ascii') != 'Buscar':

        data2, adress = sock.recvfrom(4000)

        if data2.decode('ascii') == '0':
            sock.sendto('SAIR'.encode('ascii'), adress)
            sys.exit(0)
```

O programa não recebe o 'data'. O cliente, nessa parte, está assim:

```
def buscar(): #função de buscar palavras
               sock.sendto(('BUSCAR'.encode('ascii')), (host,port))
               sock.sendto((e1.get().encode('ascii')), (host, port))
               data, adress = sock.recvfrom(4000)
               if data.decode('ascii')=='0':
                   lb2["text"] = 'Esse nome nao existe em nosso dicionario. Ajude-nos cadastrando uma nova palavra'
               else:
                   lb2["text"] = data.decode('ascii')
```

O "def buscar()" é chamado por um botão.

Comment: Primeiramente, @Diego Cândido, busque não publicar novas respostas como alternativa para atualizar o conteúdo de sua pergunta. [Edite-a](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/334495/edit), o stackoverflow fornece essa opção. E por favor, você poderia fornecer o código todo seguido do erro que retorna?

Comment: Certo. Atualizei!